PowerShell command to add a new IP\Subnet to Windows Cluster
I have a working 2 node Windows Cluster that runs SQL Server Always On Cluster.  This cluster is sitting on 10.11.x.x subnet.
I need to get this cluster ready for possible DR scenario.
I need to add a new IP on different subnet - 10.14.y.y to thsi existing Windows custer.  I will also need to add a new IP on 10.14.yy subnet to the existing AG Listener.
I used PowerShell to add a new IP Address cluster Resource to the cluster.
 Add-ClusterResource –Name IPAddress141 –ResourceType “IP Address” –Group “Cluster Group”
But now I cannot change the subnet to 10.14.y.y to configure this new IP.
What am I missing?  Do I need a second NIC configured to the new subnet?  Is there even a way to add a second subnet to an existing cluster?  Do I need to create a DR VM and add it to this cluster as a 3rd node?
Any help will be appreciated.
I tried to change the IP address on a new resource:
$res = Get-ClusterResource "IPAddress141" 
$param1 = New-Object Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterParameter $res,Address,"10.14.y.y"
$param2 = New-Object Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterParameter $res,SubnetMask,"255.255.252.0" 
$param3 = New-Object Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterParameter $res,Subnet,"10.14.z.z/zz" 
$params = $param1,$param2,$param3
$params | Set-ClusterParameter

This doesn't work.  It gives me an error that it cannot save the new ClusterParameter.
Windows cluster GUI doesn't work because it doesn't see the new subnet.

Please post the exact error message in full.

@MathiasR.Jessen, here you go:
New-Object : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.
At line:3 char:11


$param1 = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell ...


      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Object], ParameterBindingException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand



$param2 = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell ...




The following may be useful : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/failover-clustering/manage-cluster-quorum

@yanka24 Remove -ComObject, it should be New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.FailoverClusters.PowerShell.ClusterParameter -ArgumentList $res,Address,"10.14.y.y".

When the cluster becomes multi-subnet, there will be two different IP address for "Cluster Group" group and at any time only one of the IP addresses should be online and the other will be offline.Each of these "Cluster Group" IP addresses should belong to different subnets. Which IP address will be active will depend on the subnet on which the quorum owner node resides. This is closely related to quorum models that is configured. Dynamic quroum and a witness share is recommended.  This is the core cluster group for cluster management.
Additional cmdlets, Set-ClusterParameter cmdlet and Set-ClusterResourceDependency explained in the second link should be applied.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-manually-configure-tutorial-multi-subnet?view=azuresql
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/configuring-ip-addresses-and-dependencies-for-multi-subnet/ba-p/371698
